Image (as background) affected by depth of field?
Blender 4.2.1

How do I make an image, added as background, be affected by depth of field and visible in render?



Empties will never be visible in render, image planes might but that’s a bit clunky. Only use that if world background doesn’t work or your desired bg is strictly a regular photo (looks like it is). Not sure if world background is affected by depth of field or not. Worth trying.

Side note, you could artificially blur the world background if need be.

Image planes not only "might" be visible in render and affected by depth of field, they definitely are. The same goes for an HDRI if you use it as an Environment Texture in the world background. The problem you have here is, as @TheLabCat said, you are using an empty. Rendered in a scene are only objects that have a mesh surface or volumetrics (and lights depending on setting), generally speaking only things that are still visible when you disable the viewport overlays. An empty with an image is usually good for reference images like blueprints etc. that should not be rendered.

@GordonBrinkmann I meant to say they might work, not just “they might [be visible].” That was a typo, and you are correct they are real mesh objects so they will show up. It looks like your comment is a complete answer, I recommend you post it as such.

@TheLabCat Yep, sure you meant work, that's why I said "be visible and affected by dof" (which I would call "work" in this case). And it definitely works, not just might. Actually the main problem here is you cannot use images as empties for rendering, and this is merely a often asked question so it's rather a duplicate... but I'm busy and have no more time now to search adequate duplicates, maybe tomorrow.
